# Error on Following Tutorial using JAVA in Android?

Tags: java, android, list

I am newbie in android.Following [this tutorial](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/#comment-2540) except minor change in doInBackground Method.I am getting data from [Service](http://demo.ingresssolutions.com/proposalmanagement/services/locations/getAllLocations)

This is my implementation:

```
@Override
 public List<Location> loadInBackground() 
{
  long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
/ we should initialize new arrayList every time this on function call   
  //List<ProposalListItem> proposals = new ArrayList<ProposalListItem>();
 List<Location>  locations=  LocationListService.getInstance().getLocationList();
 long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Log.d(TAG, "loaded locations " + locations.size() + " in " + (t2 - t1) + " ms" + "locations" + locations);
 return locations;
}
```

This is the implementation of getLocationList:

```
    public List<Location>  getLocationList()
     {
         MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
          //Populate the MultiValueMap being serialized and headers in an HttpEntity object to use for the request
         HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, WorkflowRestService
                 .getInstance().getRequestHeaders());

         // Perform the HTTP GET request
         ResponseEntity<LocationListItemHolder> responseEntity = WorkflowRestService.getInstance().getRestTemplate()
                 .exchange(WorkflowApp.getServicesURL() + "locations/getAllLocations", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, LocationListItemHolder.class);
   Log.i("response Entity",""+responseEntity);
          // LocationListItemHolder locationInstance = new LocationListItemHolder();
  LocationListItemHolder locationInstance = responseEntity.getBody();
  if("true".equals(locationInstance.getStatus()))
 {Log.i("locationInstance.getLocationListItems if ",""+locationInstance.getLocationListItems());
   return locationInstance.getLocationListItems();
}
 else
{Log.i("locationInstance.getLocationListItems else",""+locationInstance.getLocationListItems());
 return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
 }
}
```

while this line **{Log.i("locationInstance.getLocationListItems if ",""+locationInstance.getLocationListItems());**   logcat : 01-09 21:47:54.790: 01-09 21:59:19.895: I/locationInstance.getLocationListItems if(20706): null
   and i am getting this Logcat on doInBackground method:

> 01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   ModernAsyncTask #3 01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() 01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):     at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 01-09
>   21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 01-09 21:59:19.905:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.loader.LocationListLoader.loadInBackground(LocationListLoader.java:47)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.loader.LocationListLoader.loadInBackground(LocationListLoader.java:1)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240) 01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   01-09 21:59:19.905: E/AndroidRuntime(20706):  ... 4 more

Comment: i have also manually insert data in Table can someone point me how to get data from Tables in doInBackground so that i can test that is there any error on Service or in my code

Comment: What is on line 4 of LocationListLoader.java?

Comment: import java.util.List;

Comment: not 4 on line 47 List<Location>  locations=  LocationListService.getInstance().getLocationList();

Comment: can someone respond me please its very urgent

Comment: So it looks like your LocationListService.getInstance() is returning null? Can you step into that code and check?

Comment: yes its null but i am not getting why its "null" its getting data from service. and have show you my service url its giving me data